# how to use if condtion in linq c#?

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, where-clause

I have a table of data having `startdate`, `enddate`  and time
for example

```
startdate     enddate          time
03/19/2020    03/19/2020       15:23
03/19/2020    03/20/2020       12:26
03/19/2020    03/19/2020       05:23
03/19/2020    03/19/2020       09:23
03/19/2020    03/21/2020       04:23
```

I want to use LINQ query to get a minimum of time
when startdate = enddate

I use this query

```
time = table.Where(x => x.StartDate == x.EndDate).Min(x=>x.time)
```

but when I run this code it gives me exception InValidOperationException was unhandled by user code

another query I have to use is

```
time = table.OrderBy(x=>x.StartDate == x.EndDate).First().Time
```

but it is giving me an incorrect output

Any suggestion how can I fix this

Comment: What is the type of `table`?

Comment: table is a onbject of sqltable through which we get data from sql

Comment: What are the types of startdate, enddate and time?

Comment: Does that InvalidOperationException give more details about *what* operation is invalid?

Comment: In the second case you say "it is giving me an incorrect output" - that's progress! Please add what that output is, and what you expected it to be. - Also you need to tell us whether this is an in-memory table or an RDBMS table, there are subtle differences in how Linq works in these scenarios

Comment: With an in-memory `List` of objects with StartDate and EndDate as `DateTime` properties (no time is set, so midnight) and Time as `TimeSpan`, your first query returns the correct answer (05:23). So apparently there is something "special" about your `table` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

```
time = table.OrderBy(x => x.time).FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartDate == x.EndDate)?.time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your data is really equal, they may contain invisible blank characters. If that were the case, it would lead to the problem. you can use
`table.ToList()` and set a breakpoint to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
time = table.Where(e => e.StartDate == e.EndDate).OrderBy(e => e.Time).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Welcome and apologies for messing with the voting on your comment - it was a good suggestion given our current understanding of the problem. I don't think we have enough context to be able to suggest what's wrong in this case.

Comment: well this can give you a nullreferenceexception if "table" itself is null. Can you check if you're opening a connection to table in the right way

Comment: table is not null